# operator == overload not called for implied 'true'?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm subclassing `std::optional` and need to delete the `operator==(bool)` and implement my custom `operator==(enum)`.

To delete the operator, this worked:

```
constexpr bool operator == ( bool ) noexcept = delete;
```

Works great for the code below, throwing a "deleted function" compile error

```
OptionalSubclass<int> ReturnEvens( int i ) { if ( i % 2 == 0 ) return i; return {}; }
 :
 :
auto result = ReturnEvens(42);
if ( result == true )
   std::cout << *result << " is even" << std::endl;
```

However, the below code, with an implied 'true', compiles and executes

```
auto result = ReturnEvens(42);
if ( result )
   std::cout << *result << " is even" << std::endl;
```

Is there a different operator I should be deleting?

Comment: What do You understand by "subclassing"?

Comment: Your function returns `std::optional<int>` rather than your new derived class. Is that deliberate?

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve]

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, thanks for catching my mistake. Fixed my OP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::optional` has an [`operator bool()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator_bool) that allows it to be converted to a `bool` for evaluation in a condition.  You need to delete that operator as well so it cannot be implicitly converted.

Comment: OP seems to use `std::optional` instead of his subclass. If that is the case then your answer is wrong.

Comment: @Slava OP made a mistake, but it's clear that the return object is supposed to be the derived object, not `optional<int>`.

Comment: @Rakete1111 it is not clear to me. And why do we have rules if we ignore them?

Comment: @Slava They also say the the optional code in the first block is giving an error because the deleted the operator.  So they are either modifying `optional` directly or just didn't want to show the derived class.

Comment: @NathanOliver they can say whatever. No [mcve] - never happened. This suppose not only help OP but others who will come on relevant seacrh. And what do they see? You can disable `std::optional` operator

Comment: @Slava Stop taking that rule so religiously. A MCVE is useful yes, but you don't need one if it's obvious what the question refers to.

Comment: @Rakete1111 it can be obvious for you, but not for somebody who comes with related question. So what would they see? 100K+ person validates that one can disable operator for `std::optional` itself.

Comment: @Rakete1111 and about religiously. That rule is specially created for people to eliminate typos or mistakes like this. But some folks in rush to give their answer so they can cut the corners, rules are for others, they are above rules here, right? How someone can expect novice people to follow rules if high rep ignore them?